# Display key/value pair in template from Django model

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

Sorry if the question itself is confusing. I have a model with two lists that are used as dropdown lists for the user to choose from. Everything works fine except when viewing the data it will just show the key when I want it to show the value.

**models.py**

```
class RestroomReview(models.Model):
    MEN = 'M'
    WOMEN = 'W'
    UNISEX = 'U'
    FAMILY = 'F'
    RESTROOM_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('M', 'Men'),
        ('W', 'Women'),
        ('U', 'Unisex'),
        ('F', 'Family')
    ]
    RATING_CHOICES = [
        (1, 'Poor'),
        (2, 'Average'),
        (3, 'Good'),
        (4, 'Very Good'),
        (5, 'Excellent')
    ]
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
    rest_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, 
        choices=RESTROOM_TYPE_CHOICES, 
        default=MEN
    )
    baby = models.BooleanField('Changing Table')
    needle = models.BooleanField('Sharps Container')
    handicap = models.BooleanField('Handicap Accessible')
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=False)
    posted_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
```

**review_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'restroom_rater/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div>
    <h3>{{ review.venue.name }}</h3>

    <p>Title: {{ review.title}}</p>
    <p>by {{ review.user }}</p>
    <p>Public: {{ review.public }}</p>
    <p>Type: {{ review.rest_type }}</p>
    <p>Changing Table: {{ review.baby }}</p>
    <p>Sharps Container: {{ review.needle }}</p>
    <p>Handicap Accessible: {{ review.handicap }}</p>
    <p>Rating: {{ review.rating }}</p>
    <p>Comment: {{ review.comment }}</p>
    <p>Date Posted: {{ review.posted_date }}</p>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

so in my review_detail template I want it to say 'Men', 'Women', 'Unisex', or 'Family' but instead it shows 'M', 'W', 'U', 'F'. Same thing with the rating. I would like it to display 'Poor', 'Good', etc but instead it gives the number rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
{{ review.get_rest_type_display }}
```

in general `get_FIELDNAME_display()` will give you the display value.

Comment: That’s it! Thank you!